# I am looking for editor for cross-bridge

Tags: apache-flex

I am looking for editor for crossbridge compiler that I am using for action script. I need to know which editor to use in the crossbridge environment.

Answer (score 0):

Any C++ editor is sufficient.

When you invoke the makefile you need to specify the location of your flascc SDK and GLS3D repository.

More info: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/compiling-opengl-games.html